# why my animation doesn't apply everywhere?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, styling

I want to apply an animation to multiple items using a keyframe and the javascript animation method so that when the timer goes to 0 on each individual timer it will flash yellow , I have 12 in total:

```
const allAreas = [
  createArea('area-1',  60 * 60),
  createArea('area-2',  10* 60),
  createArea('area-3', 10 * 60),
  createArea('area-4', 10* 60),
  createArea('area-5', 40* 60),
  createArea('area-6', 50 * 60),
  createArea('area-7', 90 * 60),
  createArea('area-8', 20 * 60),
  createArea('area-9', 30 * 60),
  createArea('area-10', 90 * 60),
  createArea('area-12', 120 * 60), 
];

function updateTimer() {
  let uiBarContainer = document.querySelector('.area-wrapper');
  for (const area of allAreas) {
    const time = area.getTime()
    if (time > 0) {
      area.setTime(time - elapsedSecondsPerInterval);
      if (area.getTime() === 0) {
        area.ui.time.innerHTML = "Finished"
        uiBarContainer.style.animation="timeOut 4s linear infinite";
        //if the timer gets to 0, the areawrapper will flash yellow.
      }
```

CSS

```
@keyframes timeOut {
  0% { background-color: FFFF80; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px FFFF80; }
50% { background-color: E6E600; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px E6E600; }
100% { background-color: FFFF80; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px FFFF80; }
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="area-wrapper">
          <div class="area-1-timer">
        <span id="time-area-1"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

at the moment it only flashes yellow in one of the 12 areas, or if one of the timers goes to 0 in any area, it will only flash in the first area, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the `createArea` function and turn your code into a snippet?